# In R, convert list from API result into dataframe

Tags: r, list, api

I am trying to use the following API to get some data. However the results come as a list of lists, and I am having trouble converting it into a dataframe I can use. Can anyone please help?

```
library(httr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)


resp <- GET("https://api.wto.org/timeseries/v1/data?i=ITS_CS_AX6&r=188,222,320,340,558,591,826&p=000&pc=SA,SB,SC,SD,SE,SF,SG,SH,SI,SJ,SK&ps=2010-2020&subscription-key=3134a3b9d8884ba991e0bfe2f2902c4f")

df<-fromJSON(rawToChar(resp$content))
```

How do I turn `df` into a dataframe?

Thanks a lot!

`resp` looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what `resp` look like ? There is no way we can help without seeing the structure first.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to show resp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. The `jsonlite::fromJSON()` function is great but if you are not sure about the structure of the input, the output can be unpredictable. However it's usually a pretty good first step.

In your case, if you run `class(df)` R will tell you that you have a `list`. If you look at the length of the list with `length(df)`, it will return `1`. If you look at `class(df[[1]])` you will get `data.frame`. So:

```r
df <- df[[1]]


class(df)
# [1] "data.frame"

head(df)

#   IndicatorCategoryCode            IndicatorCategory IndicatorCode                                                  Indicator ReportingEconomyCode ReportingEconomy
# 1                ITS_CS Trade in commercial services    ITS_CS_AX6 Commercial services exports by sector and partner – annual                  320        Guatemala
# 2                ITS_CS Trade in commercial services    ITS_CS_AX6 Commercial services exports by sector and partner – annual                  320        Guatemala
# 3                ITS_CS Trade in commercial services    ITS_CS_AX6 Commercial services exports by sector and partner – annual                  320        Guatemala
# 4                ITS_CS Trade in commercial services    ITS_CS_AX6 Commercial services exports by sector and partner – annual                  320        Guatemala
# 5                ITS_CS Trade in commercial services    ITS_CS_AX6 Commercial services exports by sector and partner – annual                  320        Guatemala
```

Comment: Hi sorry I don't understand your comment. Also when I run ```class(df)``` it tells me I have a list. So my issue is how to convert this into a ```dataframe```.

Comment: You have a list with one element which is a dataframe. Or at least I do when I run your code. So if you do `df <- df[[1]]` you extract the dataframe.

Comment: When I run the code ```df <- df[[1]]``` it gives me a "large list of 500 elements" rather than a dataframe for ```df```. Do you think it is because of the packages I installed such as ```jsonlite```? I don't know how we could get different results. This code is very odd for me as previously it worked fine with a dataframe output and now it is giving me these lists.

Comment: I don't know why we're getting different results. It could be because of different package versions. As your `df` a list of 500 elements, it sounds like you have a list of rows. As you have `dplyr` loaded, can you do `df  <- bind_rows(df)`?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot that worked well! I will experiment with the packages installed and give an update later on the issue.